# WebService Calling Exception 401

Tags: web-services, webservice-client

Hi i am creating client from my webservice. Client is generated successfully but when I call that from java code It throws following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Failed to access the WSDL at: https://ebs-uat.corp.chartercom.com/csg_cter/2.06/orderdetailservice.asmx?wsdl. It failed with: 
Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: https://ebs-uat.corp.chartercom.com/csg_cter/2.06/orderdetailservice.asmx?wsdl.
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.tryWithMex(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:151)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:133)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.parseWSDL(WSServiceDelegate.java:254)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(WSServiceDelegate.java:217)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(WSServiceDelegate.java:165)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl.createServiceDelegate(ProviderImpl.java:93)
at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:56)
at com.charter.enterprise.billing.csg.orderdetails.OrderDetailServicePort.<init>(OrderDetailServicePort.java:68)
at com.charter.enterprise.billing.csg.orderdetails.OrderDetailServiceClient.main(OrderDetailServiceClient.java:18)

Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: https://ebs-uat.corp.chartercom.com/csg_cter/2.06/orderdetailservice.asmx?wsdl
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1436)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:234)
at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1010)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.createReader(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:793)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.resolveWSDL(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:251)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:118)
... 7 more
```

It throws exception in first line when creating webservice port

```
DataServicePort dataServicePort = new DataServicePort();
```

My complete client class is:

```
public class OrderDetailServiceClient {
    @WebServiceRef
    private static OrderDetailServicePort orderDetailServicePort;
    private static OrderDetailService orderDetailService;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        orderDetailServicePort = new OrderDetailServicePort();
        orderDetailService = orderDetailServicePort.getOrderDetailService();
        // Add your code to call the desired methods.

        System.out.println("Before calling method!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
        verifyOrderDetail();
    }

    private static void verifyOrderDetail() {
        BindingProvider prov = (BindingProvider) orderDetailService;
        prov.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.USERNAME_PROPERTY,
            "CHTR\tst_aopebstest");
        prov.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.PASSWORD_PROPERTY,
            "T$t_@0p3B$t#sT");
        orderDetailService = (OrderDetailService) prov;

        VerifyOrderDetailRequest verifyOrderDetailRequest = new VerifyOrderDetailRequest();

        VerifyOrderDetailResponse verifyOrderDetailResponse = orderDetailService
            .verifyOrderDetail(verifyOrderDetailRequest, null);

    }
}
```

I can hit in my browser. And it is also working in SoapUI. Where am I going wrong?
Any suggestion will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: post more of your code please

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can't access that web service, have you tried accessing that web service through a web browser?

Comment: Thanks @Ash for your quick response. Yes. I can hit that web service in browser. And It is also working in SoapUI also. But not working in java code. I have updated my question also. Can you please see this again.

Comment: This is just to let you know: https://ebs-uat.corp.chartercom.com/csg_cter/2.06/orderdetailservice.asmx?wsdl. Is the . (dot) supposed to be there in the ?wsdl.    ??

Comment: WSDL is associated with url. I am not getting you completely. Can you please elaborate more?

Comment: I mean the last letter of your URL there is a dot. Is the dot supposed to be there?

Comment: Actually .(dot) is applied by eclipse output console. In real case .(dot) is not applied. Last part is `?wsdl`